If $A$ is a countable subset of a vector space, there exists a linearly independent subset $B$ of $A$ such that $\text{span}(A) = \text{span}(B)$
I am trying to prove by induction the following problem:

If $V$ is a vector space and $A$ is a countable subset of $V$, prove that there exists a linearly independent subset $B$ of $A$ such that $\text{span}(A) = \text{span}(B)$.

So the way I would go about this problem is by induction: Take $A = \{x_n\}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ to be a countable subset of $V$. For the base case, we can take $B = \{x_1\}$ which is linearly independent, i.e. for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $\alpha x_1 = 0$ implies $\alpha = 0$. And also, when $n = 1$, we have $\text{span}(A) = \text{span}(B)$. Now assume, for the inductive hypothesis, that $A = \{x_1,..., x_n\}$ is a countable subset of $V$, and there exists a linearly independent $B$ of $A$ such that $\text{span}(A) = \text{span}(B)$. Then we show that for $n + 1$, if $A = \{x_1,..., x_{n + 1}\}$, then there is a linearly independent subset $B'$ of $A$ such that $\text{span}(A) = \text{span}(B')$. However, if $A = \{x_1,..., x_{n + 1}\}$, then we have $\text{span}(B) \subset \text{span}(A)$, so in order to make their spans equal, we can add an element, $\{x_{n + 1}\}$ to $B$, i.e. $B' = B \cup \{x_{n + 1}\}$, which is still linearly independent, and that would make $\text{span}(B') = \text{span}(A)$.
I am a little bit iffy with how I justified that $B'$ is linearly independent, but other than that, I am wondering if the rest of the proof should be okay. Appreciate the help.

Can you even use induction w infinity, even countable? Better minds than myself will verify but I don't think you can.

Induction only tells you that every finite set has the property. It does not show that every infinite subset has the property.

There are a couple of minor problems and one major problem in what you write.
Minor problem: you are not assuming the vectors in $A$ are nonzero. So how do you justify that $\{x_1\}$ is linearly independent? What if $x_1=\mathbf{0}$? Your assertion that $\alpha x_1=\mathbf{0}$ implies $\alpha=0$ only holds if you know that $x_1=\mathbf{0}$, and you do not. Of course, the solution to this is to take $B=\varnothing$ when $x_1=\mathbf{0}$.
Minor problem 2: You never explain how to construct $B$ in the inductive step. Presumably, you let $B$ be a linearly independent subset $B$ of $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ with $\mathrm{span}(B)=\mathrm{span}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$... but you need to say so.
Minor problem 3: How do you justify that taking $B'=B\cup\{x_{n+1}\}$ is linearly independent? You don't. You just assert that it is. It doesn't have to be. Instead you have to argue that if $x_{n+1}\in\mathrm{span}(B)$, then $x_{n+1}\in\mathrm{span}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, so $\mathrm{span}(A)=\mathrm{span}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\mathrm{span}(B)$, so you can just take $B$ again.
Major problem: Induction only tells you that you can do this for any finite set $A$; it does not let you "reach" the case of $A$ that is countably infinite. So even after fixing the problems above, you have to discuss how to bridge the gap between the finite cases and the infinite cases.
For the case where $A$ is infinite, proceed inductively to construct $B$ as you outline: let $B_0=\varnothing$. Assuming you have constructed a linearly independent subset $B_k$ of $\{x_1,\ldots,x_k\}$ with $\mathrm{span}(B_k)=\mathrm{span}(x_1,\ldots,x_k\}$, let $B_{k+1}$ be
$$B_{k+1} = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
B_k & \text{if }x_{k+1}\in\mathrm{span}(x_1,\ldots,x_{k}\},\\
B_k\cup\{x_{k+1}\} &\text{if }x_{k+1}\notin\mathrm{span}(x_1,\ldots,x_k).
\end{array}\right.$$
Now argue that $B_{k+1}$ is linearly independent, a subset of $\{x_1,\ldots,x_{k+1}\}$, and that $\mathrm{span}(B_{k+1}) = \mathrm{span}(x_1,\ldots,x_{k+1})$.
Finally, let $B=B_1\cup B_2\cup\cdots\cup B_n\cup \cdots$, and prove that $B$ is linearly independent, a subset of $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$, and that $\mathrm{span}(B)=\mathrm{span}(\{x_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty})$.
(This argument can be used to solve the finite case as well by simply extending your list by repeating the last element infinitely many times if the original list is finite.)
